# Exit Using block

Tags: vb.net

I have similar code to that:

```
Using conn As OdbcConnection = getNewConnection()

'' Some code

If breakFlag Then
     canExit = True
     GoTo exitUpdate
End If

exitUpdate:
End Using
```

I would like to get rid of GOTO statement.
For that will be handy to have ExitUsing command, but we haven't.

Is here some good way for exit Using block in similar situation or I have to design my code differently?

Comment: A `Using` block isn't really a control structure in the same sense that a `While` or `For` loop is.  It's simply a wrapper for the `Dispose` pattern.  So there may or may not be a reason to do anything outside of the `Using` block, depending on what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Using conn As OdbcConnection = getNewConnection()
    '' Some code

    If breakFlag Then
         canExit = True
         ' remove this: GoTo exitUpdate
    ELSE
        ' here place the rest of your logic that would execute when breakflag = false
    End If
End Using
```